# how do i search for lines that dont contain a specific letter using grep? (in bash)

Tags: bash, grep

I have this:

```
findError=`cut -d" " -f2 $2 | grep -i -c [^a-z,A-Z,-]`
```

but it doesnt work... I want to get the lines that f2 in it contain something that is not a letter or "-"

what am I doing wrong?

answer:

findError=`cut -d" " -f2 $2 | grep -i -c [^a-zA-Z-]`

Comment: What is $2? What output do you get? BTW, You don't need the coma; I think you could try with `[^a-zA-Z-]` or `[^[:alpha:]-]`

Comment: "Does not contain a letter" is very different fron "contains something that is not a letter". Decide which one you want.

Comment: I want "contains something that is not a letter or - " 
nd it stells doent work

Comment: `[^[:alpha:]-]` should work just fine. It will pick up "ab.", "a*b", but not "ab" or "a-b" because there are only letters and "-". If you want "does not contain a letter", `grep -v '[[:alpha:]-]'` will work because -v inverts the logic. In other words, it will match all lines that do not have any letters or "-" in them.